# Print array element value in a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, locale

There is a problem with printing array element values in the below code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "associationMaxRtx maxIncomingStream maxOutgoingStream initialAdRecWin maxUserdataSize mBuffer nThreshold PathMaxRtx maxInitialRtrAtt minimumRto maximumRto initialRto rtoAlphaIndex tSack" C:\Users\ephajin\logs.txt') do (
     set /A count+=1
     set vartmp1=%%a
     set vartmp2=%%b
     set "array[!count!]="%%a %%b""
)



(for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do  echo !array[%%i]!
) > result.txt
```

in the result file I get the output

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

It does not print the array values.

The problem is probably due to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` but how do you correct it?

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,4) DO ECHO !array[%%a]!

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a  IN ('set array[') DO ECHO %%b
```

Either of these two lines should show you what you appear to require.

Since the first is identical in effect to your code, I suspect that the `array[*]` array isn't being established correctly. you can check this by executing

```
set array[
```

to show precisely what has been set. Actually,

```
set
```

should show you all defined user-variables.

```
set|more
```

would show the same, but allow you to page through them.

```
SET "result="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a  IN ('set array[') DO SET "result=!result! %%b"
ECHO result: "%result%" or "%result:~1%"
echo===============
SET "result="
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,4) DO SET "result=!result! !array[%%a]!"
ECHO result: "%result%" or "%result:~1%"
```

Two methods of setting `result` - the list of the values in the array. Naturally, the space in the `set` instruction could be almost any character you desire - comma, for instance. The result is shown both with a leading space and with that space removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.actually i want to store !array[%%i]! result to a variable,can u please help me for the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i tried with the below code                     
(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a  IN ('set array[') DO SET "result=%%b"

ECHO "%result%" ) > result.txt but in result file i am recieving below output:                                                       C:\Users\ephajin>SET "result="rtoAlphaIndex 3"" 

C:\Users\ephajin>SET "result="rtoAlphaIndex 3""                     i want only "rtoAlphaIndex 3" as output.please help me for the same

Comment: It's not possible to come to any conclusions from the code you've posted without knowing what the values are that are assigned to `array[*]` and which value or values you want. There's no apparent point in assigning a value to `result` and then attempting to output that value without using `delayedexpansion` or `call echo %%result%%`. Pointless when `echo %%b` should do the same thing - in pursuit of an unspecified objective. Please edit your **full** actual code, input data and expected output as an addition into your original question.